# How to use Async.Parallel within an async workflow?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, mailboxprocessor

I've been trying to learn how to use asynchronous message based methods.  Below is a simplified version of what I was trying to do.  I'm trying to use a finite state machine within a `MailboxProcessor` within an object.  Overall it appears that the logic can be much more straightforward compared to using event based methods.  I have an issue though when I try to use `Async.Parallel`.  In the code following the `printfn "Eval %i" v` statement is getting evaluated twice for `i1` & `i2` instead of just one time for each. Which leads me to believe that I am not properly using `Async.Parallel`. Is there an alternative method that should be used within an asynchronous workflow?

```
type Input(v) = 

    let agent = 
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> 
            let rec loop() = 
                async { 
                    let! (msg : AsyncReplyChannel<int>) = inbox.Receive()
                    printfn "Eval %i" v
                    msg.Reply(v)
                    return! loop()
                }
            loop())

    member this.Eval = agent.PostAndAsyncReply(fun r -> r)

let i1 = Input(1)
let i2 = Input(2)

async { 
    let! nodeValues = [ i1; i2 ]
                      |> Seq.map(fun n -> n.Eval)
                      |> Async.Parallel
    return nodeValues
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: You don't need the `async { }` block. `[ i1; i2 ] |> Seq.map (fun n -> n.Eval) |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously` will work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the actual implementation does not run synchronously. My question is on how to evaluate an array of async returns (the `Eval` method in this case) in parallel within an async workflow.  See [link](https://gist.github.com/mndrake/8440854#file-utopia-fsx-L121) for an larger example.

Comment: Maybe just pass the result of `Async.Parallel` into `Async.Ignore |> Async.Start`? What do you want to do with the results from `Eval` once they're done?

Comment: In fsi under VS2010, I only see the `Eval 1` and `Eval 2` printed out once with the code above, as would be expected. What's your environment?

Comment: I'm running it in VS2012 (F# 3.0). See https://gist.github.com/mndrake/8440854 line 121 for additional reference.  I'm evaluating dependent nodes to see if they have a valid result and if so applying a function in a child task that sends a message back to a mailbox when complete.  I'm try to do not block the thread the mailbox is on otherwise it would have a cascading impact.  I get the desired impact if I add `let! n1 = i1.Eval; let! n2 = i2.Eval; let nodeValues = [| n1; n2 |]`. That obviously is not a solution that scales though.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I stumbled across a bug. It runs as expected if I change the `nodeValues` definition to `let! nodeValues = [| i1; i2 |] |> Array.map(fun n -> n.Eval) |> Async.Parallel`. Anyone run across different behavior between `Seq.map` versus `Array.map` within an async workflow before?

Comment: Sorry about the additional comments, but I cannot edit prior comments yet. I created an example on tryfsharp.org (http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/mndrake/async_error.fsx). I got the same output as my local machine.  Just by changing it from a `Seq.map` to an `Array.map` seems to be the answer.  When I look on MSDN it shows an example of using `Seq.map` with `Async.Parallel` though. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in F# 3.0.  `Async.Parallel` calls `Seq.toArray` twice.  Run your code under F# 3.1 and it will only print once.  [Here's the fix in the F# source repository.](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/commit/5ab240378c7b903934ca6cbeb85ddbd74dce31ab)

Comment: Thanks for the help gradbot.  I didn't think to check the github source.  It looks like the `Async.Parallel` method has enough dependencies that it's more than just a minor snippet that I would need if I wanted to use the 3.1 methodology in VS2012. When I'm using `Array.map` and starting with an array going into the `Async.Parallel` method is the `Seq.toArray` call effectively getting ignored then?  I guess what I'm asking does using `Array.map` in F# 3.0 solve the issue or do I need to avoid Async.Parallel in 3.0 altogether?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, and yes if you use Array.map it will work correctly.  The bug will still happen in the F# source but it will just be converting your array into a sequence and then back into an array twice.  I believe this is an design flaw.  `Async.parallel` should take an array to begin with and not a sequence.  It doesn't actually support lazy evaluation and this could lead some users astray.